# eclipse support for axis2

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache, apache-axis

I have tried to use eclipse pluggins for web services in the past, specifically for CXF, and had a **really bad** experience.
That was a couple of years ago and I am not sure if it has improved (i think it hasn't thought).
Anyway I have to look into axis2 and was wondering if the eclipse pluggins for axis2 are working ok.
Does anyone has experience in axis2/eclipse to tell me if using eclipse for axis2 has any issues?  Should I give it a try or I will lose time?
Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote?It is ok, but at least there should be some explanation.Otherwise what is the point?

Comment: I really wish that Eclipse had better support for webservices in general.  Not supporting [Metro](http://metro.java.net/), despite it being [shipped with Java 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/package-summary.html), is just stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're looking to get out of said support. If you want to be able to generate calls against a running Axis2 servier, then Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) is pretty handy.

It lets you run a webserver from inside eclipse, and generates a form GUI from a WSDL file for testing webservices. I've used it with Tomcat and Axis2 and found it to be pretty handy.

Comment: What about the client stubs generation?Is there any support there?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but apparently so: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [WSO2 Carbon Studio](http://wso2.org/library/carbon-studio) - which is an eclipse based open source tool...

Thanks...